# What is benefit using of costom scope in Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

What is the benefit of using a custom scope to inject an instance to an android component and limit its alive time to lifecycle owner? If we use @Singletone and the instance be alive in the entire application what happens? Is there a performance issue or architectural?

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are really important in Dagger 2. They kind of show an hierarchy of the dependencies.

> If we use @Singletone and the instance be alive in the entire
>   application what happens?

Once you have instantiated a `Singleton` instance , there will be provided only one for your entire component marked with the `@Singleton` annotation.

> Is there a performance issue or architectural?

No, that's the problem that the `@Singleton` solves really. You don't need to call instances again and again since they are provided in your Application level. Which means it's quite the opposite. Those get alive once you have called the `@Inject` annotation , which is a command that calls the dependencies you require once you declared them in your `Singleton` module.

Example:

```
@Module(includes = [InterceptorModule::class])
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTreasureApi(retrofit: Retrofit): TreasureApi = retrofit.create(TreasureApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(PRAYER_API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
}
```

This module provides the Retrofit instance and my interface builder, which I will need in the whole app. In case not using dagger, this instances would still be instantiated in the Application level in the `onCreate` method and would find a way to call them on the other levels of the app.

As for your title question:

> What is benefit using of costom scope in Dagger 2?

It doesn't really matter the difference between `@Singleton` or `@AnotherAnnotation` as a custom annotation, just make sure that when you mark a component with `@AnotherAnnotation` those dependencies on the inside module will only be instantiated on the `AnotherAnnotation` level.

I don't really use the `@Singleton` annotation on my app level dependencies but I do it only because it's cooler like that, not that it makes some difference.

No in order to convince you about that check this out: This is the code of the `@Singleton` annotation in Java:

```
@Scope
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Singleton {}
```

And this is the implementation of my own annotation in Kotlin, which you will notice there is nothing different apart from the `@Documented` annotation, which has nothing to do with our case.

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ApplicationScope
```